# How to add authorization in sendRequest method in postman

Tags: postman

I try to call another api  from test script,below code i have added in the test script,but after run the api i got the output like

```
      var options = {
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': pm.globals.get("domainName")+'api/test',
        'header': {
        'authorization': 'Bearer '+pm.globals.get("token")
    }
 };
  pm.sendRequest(options, function (err, response) {
  console.log(response.json());
   });
```

output

```
  {status: false, message: "Your request did not contain the access token in the authorization header"}
    status: false
    message: "Your request did not contain the access token in the authorization header"
```

I have added the authorization token properly but still it give me an error
Please help me where i am doing wrong
Thank you

Comment: Can you show the console log? I want to see the actual request that sent to server.

Comment: Thank you for replay,but issue is resolve now

Answer (score 0):

just create a normal request and in the test script session add the below line

```
 pm.environment.set("request",pm.request)
```

now you can use this request any where

```
 pm.sendRequest(pm.environment.get("request"))
```

you can view the structure as :

```
 console.log(JSON.stringify(pm.environment.get("request"),null,2))
```